# Update only few records in a table in my sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

i have a table as shown below picture , need to update the value column to remove the '-' in data. please help me with this.

[image]

Comment: How many records are you trying to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your value is number type,you can try to use `ABS` function.

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET value = ABS(value)
```

Comment: Yeah `ABS` will return an absolute value It means positive value, nice answer

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE table_t SET column_c = REPLACE(column_c , '-', '');